# what is the most compatible GDB version to use with Nemiver?

Tags: debugging, lambda, gdb, backwards-compatibility, nemiver-debugger

what is the most compatible GDB version to use with Nemiver? or how to prevent the "freezing" below?

I am getting this on debug log when nemiver stops in a break point but doesnt really stop:

- the continue button remains inactive,
- the stop button is active but nothing happens when clicked (it just dumps the below repeated log),
- clicking in threads and in frames do not update the variables,
- I am unable to continue running, nor stop it,
- the only option is to resume a saved session as there is no other way to restart it than kill nemiver process.

```
|E|bool nemiver::GDBMIParser::parse_member_variable(Glib::ustring::size_type, Glib::ustring::size_type&, nemiver::IDebugger::VariableSafePtr&, bool):nmv-gdbmi-parser.cc:3414:parsing failed for buf: >>>@0x7fffffffb540: {...}<<< cur index was: 2100
|X|bool nemiver::GDBMIParser::parse_member_variable(Glib::ustring::size_type, Glib::ustring::size_type&, nemiver::IDebugger::VariableSafePtr&, bool):nmv-gdbmi-parser.cc:3415:raised exception: should not be reached

|E|bool nemiver::GDBEngine::Priv::on_gdb_stdout_has_data_signal(Glib::IOCondition):nmv-gdb-engine.cc:1150:should not be reached
```

the problem happens at operator=() (for var = ...) just after processing this line:
`var = [this](){return SomeClassConstructor(...).setOnUpdateConverter( [this](){...} );}();`

so my guess is GDB vs Nemiver may have some limitation with lambdas?

Btw.: Nemiver has no updates for a long time already. Is there a newer nemiver somewhere that could be fully compatible with newer GDB?

Comment: Have you considered CLion as an alternative?

Comment: CLion isnt free right? I have looked about it sometime ago. Nemiver is totally free (no need to pay, no trial) and works well most of the time, but has no source code updates in like 6 https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/nemiver

Comment: No it's not free, but then your time isn't free either, so paying a little can get you a lot.  I use it on Windows, macOS and Linux and the debugger is decent and the cost is negligible, given what it offers.  Anyway, I am not on commission or anything, so just a thought.

Comment: and if I am coding a free software and getting no money from it? to me it only makes sense to use Nemiver or another 100% free debugger.